# how to pass laravel session to vue.js

Tags: laravel, session, vue.js, vuejs2

i want to pass `langguageid` session from laravel to my vue component.

how i can do it?

i try like this, but not working.

my laravel session function

```
public function getLanguageSession($langid)
{
    if (Session::has('LangSession')) {
        Session::forget('LangSession');
        $LangSession = Session::put('LangSession', $langid);
        $getLangSession = Session::get('LangSession');
    } else {
        $LangSession = Session::put('LangSession', $langid);
        $getLangSession = Session::get('LangSession');
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

and then i call it to vue function

```
 public function getLanguageStringArray(Request $request, $langid)
    {
        $getLangSession = Session::get('LangSession');
        dd($getLangSession);
}
```

this code return me null value.

Comment: Are you calling `getLanguageStringArray()` with ajax from your Vue components? If so, then you need to return json or you can also add this variable into the blade file javascript and access it with Vue.

Comment: @thefallen ya. how i call session laravel to vue template?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You should not return json data from a controller using `dd($getLangSession);`, this will give you a totally different output that cannot be parsed by Vue. You have to return the data as a json result to make sure Vue can read this:

```
public function getLanguageStringArray(Request $request, $langid)
{
    $getLangSession = Session::get('LangSession');
    return repsonse()->json($getLangSession);
}
```

Comment: it return me empty `{}` no value on it. but if i return in `getLanguageSession` it return me value.